# Executing .exe Files on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, exe, wine

I am trying to run eclipse in ubuntu12.04.After installing eclipse and WINE I tried opening eclipse by right clicking the eclipse then selecting 'open with' and selected WINE but when I'm trying to run eclipse it's showing "there is no windows program configure for this file".
Can Someone please share the steps how to configure the file with WINE

Comment: Why use Wine when there is a native version of Eclipse for Ubuntu?

Comment: Why don't you install Ubuntu version of eclipse ?

Comment: Because I downloaded android SDK and ADT plugins are already setup in eclipse I downloaded with that sdk..

Comment: There are ADT downloads for Linux

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse + ADT tools for linux, installation is a breeze. ADT for windows will not run on linux because low-level USB access isn't implemented in WINE.

Edit: Really? Because it was already setup?

Comment: I have downloaded tools for linux only but i'm unable to configure eclipse with WINE as downloaded eclipse with ADT tools is an exe file

Comment: Dowload Eclipse for Linux. Unpack. Download ADT for Linux. Unpack. Run Eclipse. [Download the ADT plugin. Configure the ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Done.